# Outside ArcMap session, script fails to add/save layer to mxd file

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

The following code generates an layer output, but fails to add and save it to the specified mxd.  There are no other layers in the mxd, and is just a 'ghost' / placeholder for running the script outside an ArcMap session.

```
import arcpy,os

fc_path = "C:\\TEMP\\Footprint.shp"
layer_name = "Footprint"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\TEMP\\Parser.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
layerfile = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, layer_name + ".lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_path, layer_name)
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(layer_name, layerfile, "ABSOLUTE")
add_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layerfile)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, add_layer)
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
mxd.save()
```

Comment: I think there is an error in your second line of code where `fc_path = "C\\TEMP\\Footprint.shp"` should probably be `fc_path = "C:\\TEMP\\Footprint.shp"`. Also I don't think Windows will let you have two folders named `C:\TEMP` and `C:\temp` on the same file system.

Comment: Fat fingered it in the question, fixed.

Comment: Remember that the code you present in a snippet here should really be a copy/paste of something that you have just tested, so that our volunteers can develop confidence that what you are describing is 100% accurate.

Comment: Do you have the MXD open while running the script?  It'll probably fail if that's the case (or at least just not save).  Your script above works as-is for me.

Comment: No arcmap open, should mention.. I'm using arc 10.1.  It works huh?  When I run it, and open the mxd - the layer is not saved in the file.  Hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not originally say what ArcGIS version you are using but when I run the test below with near identical code to yours at ArcGIS 10.4 Prerelease for Desktop it behaves as I would expect.

This is what my C:\Temp\Parser.mxd looks like prior to running the test:

[image]

I then run the code below from IDLE:

```
import arcpy,os

##arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(out_feature_class="C:/Temp/Footprint.shp",
##                               origin_coord="0 0",
##                               y_axis_coord="0 1",
##                               cell_width="1", cell_height="1",
##                               number_rows="2", number_columns="2",
##                               corner_coord="", labels="NO_LABELS",
##                               template="DEFAULT", geometry_type="POLYGON")

fc_path = "C:\\Temp\\Footprint.shp"
layer_name = "Footprint"

# Added to avoid ERROR 000725, if layer file exists
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\Temp\\Parser.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
layerfile = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, layer_name + ".lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_path, layer_name)

arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(layer_name, layerfile, "ABSOLUTE")
add_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layerfile)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, add_layer)
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
mxd.save()
```

Things to notice in my code are:

- I have left in, but commented out how I created my C:\Temp\Footprint.shp
- I added an `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` to avoid getting a 000725 error

After running the code above my C:\Temp\Parser.mxd looked like this:

[image]